# Link QLabel to variable (two different classes) in Qt C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, qt5

Currently working on getting threading to work with Qt C++ along with using the clearest method to solve the problem. Below is some code to start 3 threads and count to 10000. What i have at the moment is when u press the start and stop buttons the counters do work (using qDebug). However what I want to do is link the counter variable to 3 labels so that when the counter goes up the label for each thread does too (however had no luck with connect as not sure how to link class methods (specifically ui->label->settext to Thread::get_time())).

Currently I am stuck on the final part, as can't find a way to link to label from inside thread.cpp if anyone can help that would be great. As you can imagine gotten a bit lost and not sure where to go from here.

object.h

```
#ifndef OBJECT_H
#define OBJECT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMutex>

class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    int timealive;
public:
    explicit Object(QObject *parent = 0);
    void setup(QThread &thread, QObject &object);
    void set_time(int number);
    int get_time();
    bool Stop;
signals:

public slots:
    void worker();
};

#endif // OBJECT_H
```

dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_4_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_5_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_6_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

Dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(12));
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{

}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{

}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{

}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_6_clicked()
{

}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "object.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    QThread thread;
    Object thread_object;

    thread_object.setup(thread,thread_object);

    return a.exec();
}
```

object.cpp

```
#include "object.h"

Object::Object(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void Object::setup(QThread &thread,QObject &object)
{
    object.moveToThread(&thread);

    thread.start();
    connect(&thread,SIGNAL(started()),this,SLOT(worker()));
}

void Object::worker()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        QMutex mutex;
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
        this->set_time(i);
        qDebug() << i;
        if(this->Stop)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Object::set_time(int number)
{
   timealive = number;
}

int Object::get_time()
{
    return timealive;
}
```

Dialog.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>286</width>
    <height>168</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>261</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Number</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>40</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Start</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Stop</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>261</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Number</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>40</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_5">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Start</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_6">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Stop</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>9</x>
     <y>9</y>
     <width>261</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Number</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>40</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Start</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Stop</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Cheers ION

P.s changed code to reflect that I am now using the correct way for threading.

Comment: thought it might be this instead connect(mThread,SIGNAL(mThread->get_time()),this,SLOT(ui->label->setText(get_time())));                     however this doesnt work either (no errors but nothing happens).

Comment: Found out i've been using the incorrect way of using threads (using a subclass). So edited my code to match. so instead using move to thread instead, however my problem still stands. How do you link a variable to a Qlabel (one that is already created)

Comment: Sorry not a variable a class function that returns a int variable that can be pushed into ui->label->settext etc.